# is it possible to get JWT token to return_url via POST?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to get JWT token to return_url via POST?
Just not to leave a URL in the browser history

Additionally, I am afraid that one day the size of the JWT might exceed the max size of the URL with the query parameters

Comment: What type of app? Why is it even coming back in the URL to begin with? How are you requesting for a token? Form post response is the default nowadays.

Comment: Webapp. Openid connect. Redirects to azure as b2b sign in page which redirects the user back to the return_url with the jwt token. That token is a query parameter. So the question was how to make it POST instead.

Comment: See this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-authentication-requests), set response_mode to form_post.

Comment: Thank you, Jas. That's a good point, I've missed it